# JSON to JS array

Tags: javascript, json

**JSON:**

```
[{"CDATE":"0000-00-00","DISTANCE":"0"},
{"CDATE":"0000-00-00","DISTANCE":"1"},
{"CDATE":"0000-00-00","DISTANCE":"2"},
{"CDATE":"0000-00-00","DISTANCE":"3"}]
```

Is it possible to put all the distance value in their own array in JS? The formatting will be consistent as it comes from an API and is always formatted correctly.

**What I've tried:**

```
var arry = [ /* JSON noted above */ ];
alert(arry[1])
```

and

```
var arry = JSON.parse([ /* JSON noted above */ ]);
alert(arry[1])
```

**Expected:**

```
1
```

**Actual:**

```
{"CDATE":"0000-00-00","DISTANCE":"1"}
```

and the other gives an error.

---

I would like to extract just the `DISTANCE` value as an array of `DISTANCE`

I've tried `JSON.parse()` but I don't think this is what I am after as it hasn't worked for me.

Comment: That is what the backend is returning.  I'm using  JSON_encode($arry);  If it not JSON what is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var data = [{"CDATE":"0000-00-00","DISTANCE":"0"},
{"CDATE":"0000-00-00","DISTANCE":"1"},
{"CDATE":"0000-00-00","DISTANCE":"2"},
{"CDATE":"0000-00-00","DISTANCE":"3"}];

var distance = data.map(el => el.DISTANCE);

console.log(distance[2]);
console.log(distance);
```

It is already a valid json so you do not need to use JSON.parse()